# wxWidgets / wx Form Builder Inheritance Class Events

Tags: inheritance, wxwidgets, wxformbuilder

Windows 11, VS Studio 19
wx version 3.1.5

I used wx Form Builder to generate the code, and then the inheritance classes (once), however whenever I click on the menu item (m_Mod) it does not call the derived classes function (should create a message box with the text "CALLED", but nothing appears), which from what I can see that is how it is intended to work.

I have tried adding override, setting the events to Connect and Table, as well as impl_virtual, decl and pure virtual, and without anything of major help after an hour searching.

(If I put the code in the cMainFrame function declaration it does run, just not when its in the cMain derived class function)

Full code at: https://github.com/Miitto/Arma-Mod-Assistant

> **cGUI.h** (wxFormBuilder generated, removed some of the clutter)

```cpp
class cMainFrame : public wxFrame
{
protected:
    wxMenuBar* m_menuBar;
    wxMenu* m_file;
    wxMenu* m_New;

    virtual void newMod( wxCommandEvent &event) {event.Skip();}

    cMainFrame( wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id = id_mainFrame, const wxString& title = wxEmptyString, const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition, const wxSize& size = wxSize( 1920,1080 ), long style = wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wxTAB_TRAVERSAL );
    wxAuiManager m_mgr;
    ~cMainFrame();
};
```

> **cGUI.cpp**

```cpp
cMainFrame::cMainFrame( wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id, const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size, long style ) : wxFrame( parent, id, title, pos, size, style )
{
    this->SetSizeHints( wxDefaultSize, wxDefaultSize );
    m_mgr.SetManagedWindow(this);
    m_mgr.SetFlags(wxAUI_MGR_DEFAULT);

    m_menuBar = new wxMenuBar( 0 );
    m_file = new wxMenu();
    m_New = new wxMenu();
    wxMenuItem* m_NewItem = new wxMenuItem( m_file, wxID_ANY, wxT("New"), wxEmptyString, wxITEM_NORMAL, m_New );
    wxMenuItem* m_Mod;
    m_Mod = new wxMenuItem( m_New, id_newModMenu, wxString( wxT("Mod") ) , wxEmptyString, wxITEM_NORMAL );
    m_New->Append( m_Mod );
    m_mgr.Update();
    this->Centre( wxBOTH );

    // Connect Events
    m_New->Bind(wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED, wxCommandEventHandler( cMainFrame::newMod ), this, m_Mod->GetId());
}
```

> **cMain.h** (Inheritence Class Generated by wxFormsBuilder)

```cpp
#ifndef __cMain__
#define __cMain__
#include "cGUI.h"
class cMain : public cMainFrame
{
protected:
        // Handlers for cMainFrame events.
        void newMod( wxCommandEvent& event );
public:
    cMain( wxWindow* parent);

}
#endif
```

> **cMain.cpp**

```cpp
#include "cMain.h"
#include <wx/msgdlg.h>

cMain::cMain( wxWindow* parent )
:
cMainFrame( parent )
{

}
void cMain::newMod( wxCommandEvent& event )
{
    wxMessageBox(wxT("CALLED"));
    event.Skip();
}
```

Comment: usual stanza - wx version? OS/toolkit? And you of course need a proper `event sink` parameter to be passed to the Connect function. (BTW, why do you use Connect() (still) )?

Comment: Added vserion etc, I have tried using the event table as welll with same result - and would it be possible to elaborate on the ```event sink``` parameter

Comment: The code you posted (mostly) works for me.  I say "mostly" because I had to add the lines  `m_menuBar->Append( m_New, wxT("&ModMenu") );` and `SetMenuBar( m_menuBar );` to your cGUI.cpp.  I assume you left them out when removing clutter.  I know those lines will be generated by wxFormBuilder (I cut them from another wxFormbuilder project and pasted them into your code).  Without those lines there is no menu to click.

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but there's also no reason to use the ids `id_mainFrame` and `id_newModMenu`.  You should just leave those as `wxID_ANY` in wxFormBuilder.

Comment: Slightly weird, I do not believe I removed those lines, although I could be mistaken (|)
I gave them IDs just to check if that would work, they were originally wxID_ANY

Comment: `wxCommandEventHandler( cMainFrame::newMod )` this is for `connect` not for `bind`

Answer (score 0):

This code should definitely work, provided you actually append the menu item to the menu bar, so you can click it (as already mentioned by @New Pagodi). And as mentioned by @macroland, you don't need `wxCommandEventHandler` with `Bind()`, using it can just hide potential mistakes (even though this is not the case here). The recommended and simpler way is to just write this line as:

```cpp
m_New->Bind(wxEVT_MENU, &cMainFrame::newMod, this, m_Mod->GetId());
```

But, again, the code as shown does work, so you really need to show the actual code you use because it seems you've somehow fixed your problem while simplifying it. Of course, now that you did fix it, you should also be easily able to find the problem yourself just by comparing the version you posted here with the one you have.

Comment: I've added a GitHub link for the full project
Even with the code edits provided, I cannot get even the simplified version to work so I'm starting to think it's something to do with my end :/

Answer (score 0):

A cMain object that inherits from cMainFrame is not created anywhere in your full code. The cApp class should be modified as shown below.

cApp.h

```cpp
#include "cMain.h"

class cApp : public wxApp
{

//...
public:
    cMain* m_main = nullptr;
//...

}
```

cApp.cpp

```cpp
bool cApp::OnInit()
{
    m_main = new cMain(nullptr);
    m_main->Show();

    return true;
}
```